# Are redundant default initializations omitted?

Tags: initialization, d

One of the curious aspects of D when compared to C or C++ is that variables are default initialized according to their type when an assignment value isn't provided.

```
int foo() {
    int o; // int.init == 0
    o++;
    return o; // returns 1
}
```

In contrast to C and C++, which simply leaves variables with potential garbage, D makes sure that garbage is never read from nearly all types of variables. However, considering this simple, merely hypothetical function, `r` is never read before being set to `i`, and it is certain that the assignment will happen eventually.

```
int foo2(int n) {
    assert(n > 0 && n < 20);
    int r;
    for (int i = n ; ; i+=7) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            r = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

1. In a case where it is certain that a variable will be defined in the
   future without a previous read, will the default initialization
   still happen, according to the standard?
2. Is it known from the DMD/GDC compilers to optimize them out (as in, omitting default
   initialization when that default value is never read from the
   variable)?
3. If none of the above, is there a nice work-around to
   having a completely uninitialized variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. In a case where it is certain that a variable will be defined in the future without a previous read, will the default initialization still happen, according to the standard?

Since D doesn't have value-type constructors (default `struct` constructors), initialization should not have any side effects, thus compilers are allowed to optimize it away. I believe this is a subset of dead assignment elimination.

> 2. Is it known from the DMD/GDC compilers to optimize them out (as in, omitting default initialization when that default value is never read from the variable)?

The language specification does not impose a constraint on what optimizations an implementation *must* perform. The above example is non-trivial, so I would not be surprised if e.g. DMD would not optimize it away, or if GDC will on the maximum optimization level.

> 3. If none of the above, is there a nice work-around to having a completely uninitialized variable?

Yes: `int r = void;`